# jquery date picker setting minDate and maxDate

Tags: jquery

I want to set date of birth with JQuery datepicker so i need the user to have an option of year from 1930 till date and the months to be complete. PLease how do i do it?

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      minDate: -20, maxDate: "+12M +31D",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    });
});
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Answer (score 0):

You can to do like this:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      yearRange: "1930:2012",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
```

Then

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', new Date(startDate));
$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', new Date(endDate));
```

or

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', { minDate: new Date(startDate),
                              maxDate: new Date(endDate) });
```